# How to convert the data type of a column in access from short text to date in Ms Access?

Tags: vba, date, ms-access, access-data-project

I am importing data from Excel to Access Table using VBA. One of the column has date in the form dd.mm.yyyy but it is stored as short text. How can I change the short text data type to date as dd.mm.yyyy.

Initially I had set the table column as type date but I was not able to import data due to data type mismatch.

Therefore, once the data is in the access table, I would like to change the data type to date with format dd.mm.yyyy.

Comment: Thank you for your help. There was already date in the field as dd.mm.yyyy, When I was trying to convert this column to date using DateValue, it did not work. Now I am replacing dd.mm.yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy and then I am able to convert it to Date using the DateValue()

Answer (score 0):

Add a new field to the table, TrueDate, and update it using this expression:

```
DateSerial(Mid([TextDate], 7), Mid([TextDate], 4, 2), Mid([TextDate], 1, 2))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. There was already date in the field as dd.mm.yyyy, When I was trying to convert this column to date using DateValue, it did not work. Now I am replacing dd.mm.yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy and then I am able to convert it to Date using the DateValue()

UPDATE MiddleTable SET F7 = Replace([F7], ".", "/"); 
UPDATE MiddleTable SET F7 = DateValue([F7]);

Comment: OK. Double-check that _mm_ and _dd_ for `dd <= 12` are not reversed.